# Linking libstdc++ issue on RHEL 5.7

Tags: c++, linker, g++, libstdc++

I would like to create a statically linked binary with the following command:

```
g++ -o bin/target_binary objs/obj1.o objs/obj2.o objs/obj3.o -I/usr/include/c++/4.1.1/ -O3 -Wall -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/32 -Wl,-verbose
```

The relevant part of the output:

```
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/32/libstdc++.a succeeded
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /lib/../lib64/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/../lib64/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libstdc++.a failed
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/32/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

g++ -v

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
```

uname -a

```
Linux vmh-caipi-reporting.lsy.fra.dlh.de 2.6.18-274.18.1.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jan 20 15:11:18 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsb_release -a

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga)
Release:    5.7
Codename:   Tikanga
```

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, the gcc version history seems to imply that `-static-libstdc++` has been included since 4.5.0, which is a whole 3 years newer than your 4.1.2. Maybe you should consider a gcc upgrade?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to change anything on the OS.

Comment: In that case, you should try the tutorial at http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

The problem seems to be that you have 32-bit `libstdc++.a`, but not a 64-bit one.

Find out where the 32-bit version came from: `rpm -qf /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/32/libstdc++.a`, and try to install equivalent 64-bit package.

If there is no existing package that provides 64-bit `libstdc++.a` (that's *very* unlikely), you can grab the source RPM for your `gcc`, and rebuild it. That should give you a usable 64-bit version of `libstdc++.a`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to change anything on the OS, but normally this would solve the problem, I assume. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @bayerb Building your own libstdc++.a does not require changing anything in the OS.